# python regular expression for music chord names

Tags: python, regex

I want to seperate the music chord string.

For example

`AEDm` to `[A,E,Dm]`

`DmEbD7` to `[Dm,Eb,D7]`

`DmF#` to `[Dm,F#]`

The code I made is below

```
m = re.match("([A-Z][#bm7]*)([A-Z][#bm7]*)+",chord_name_str)
print(group(m))
```

but it match `FGAm` to `[F,Am]` not `[F,G,Am]`

Where am I wrong??

Comment: How about slash cords like `C/G` or diminished chords like `Cdim`? 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use just one capturing group here and achieve the result you're seeking.

```
chords = ['AEDm', 'DmEbD7', 'DmF#', 'FGAm']
for chord in chords:
    print(chord, re.findall("([A-Z][#bm7]*)",chord))

    
#AEDm ['A', 'E', 'Dm']
#DmEbD7 ['Dm', 'Eb', 'D7']
#DmF# ['Dm', 'F#']
#FGAm ['F', 'G', 'Am']
```